# Interpreting having known

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

Please look at the following sentence

> 1. Having lived all my life in India, I can speak Hindi very well.

Does this mean I still live in India, or can it also be used if I have just moved from India to USA? If yes, then can it  also be used if I have been living in USA for 1 year, when I speak these words?

> a. Having known her, I can tell she won't be happy.
>   b. Knowing her, I can tell she won't be happy.

What's the difference between #a and #b? Can #a ever be used, because it is difficult to 'un-know' someone after knowing them. In light of this should always #b be used ?

Also, if I want to say that I have known her 5 years and still know her, then which form must I employ

> c. Having known her for 5 years, I can tell she won't be happy
>   d. Knowing her for 5 years, I can tell she won't be happy.

Thank you.

Comment: Also,we'd probably say "Knowing her, she won't be happy", not "I can tell", since "I can tell" means "I can discern {something} from available clues or hints". For example  "I could tell she wasn't happy by how she was tapping her foot."  "I can tell when he's getting angry; his brow furrows."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The present perfect conceptualizes the past thing from the point of view of its relation to the present.

> Having eaten pumpkin pie, I know what it tastes like.

My present knowledge is the result of eating pumpkin pie at some point prior to "now".  The eating might have taken place 1 second ago or 1 year ago or 10 years ago. I might have some unfinished pie on a plate in front of me. All we know from the tense is that I am  someone who ate some pumpkin pie at some time in the past.

With "having lived", if you said this and only this:

> Having lived in India, I am familiar with the cuisine.

all that can be concluded from the statement is that you lived in India at some period in the past. It could be last week, or last year, or for the past 20 years. You are a person who can truthfully say "I lived in India". You might live there still.

Now, let's see if we complicate things by adding "all my life".

> Having lived in India all my life, I am familiar with the cuisine.

**All my life** does not exclude the present moment; nor does it necessarily include it.  You can easily say, as someone who has emigrated to Antarctica, "I lived in India all my life. But now I live here at the South Pole. Aren't the freezing temperatures refreshing?"

So, we cannot conclude from the statement whether you are living in India now, or have moved elsewhere.  All we know is that you are a person who can claim to be someone who, at some time in the (recent) past, had been living in India since birth. **all my life** does not exclude the present but it does guarantee it: a person who had been born in India and who had lived there *until very recently*, could say "Having lived in India all my life..."

So, yes, you can say "having lived" whether you have moved away, or you still live there.

Comment: "I lived in India all my life. But now I live here at the South Pole. Aren't the freezing temperatures refreshing?" can this be said even after we have lived in Antarctica for 4 long continuous years as we speak? Also, why shouldn't 'all my life' always include the present moment ? In what sense are you using 'all my life' here?

ALSO, please address the #c and #d part of the of the above question. Thanks

Comment: "All my life" does not necessarily include the present moment. It does not necessarily exclude it.  Unlike absolute time-references such as "yesterday", the meaning of "all my life" is context-dependent.  You could even say "I plan to live here all my life" of a place to which you had just moved a week ago. Clearly it does not refer to your life since birth.

Comment: You other examples of the perfect are no different. Knowing, however, is present. Eating pumpkin pie, I now know what it tastes like.

Comment: @Policewala Both #c and #d convey that the speaker has known _her_ for five years. The assumption is that this "knowing" is still in progress. To say otherwise, the speaker would have to put the "knowing" explicitly in the past: _I **knew** her for five years, (and) I can tell she won't be happy._

Comment: Without any context to the contrary, the phrase _Having lived all my life in India_ does imply that the speaker currently lives in India, since the speaker is clearly still amongst the living. On the other hand, this would tell the reader that the speaker _previously_ lived in India: _Having lived all my life in India until recently..._

Comment: @P.E. Dant: Hindi speaker goes to Antarctica to live. A guy from Texas who has also moved to the South Pole says, "Ever had one of these here naans?" To which the Hindi speaker replies, "Having lived in India all my life, I am familiar with the cuisine."  The Hindi speaker is not living in India now.

Comment: @TRomano Precisely! Thus "Without any context to the contrary..." in my comment.

Comment: How is the Texan supposed to know from that sentence whether the Hindi speaker is there on a short visit, intending to return to India, or has emigrated? Why should he assume that he is still living in India?

Comment: @TRomano Late seeing this! Well, were I this putative cowpoke, I would have the needed context already in mind. If I encountered Prasad in the warrens of Little America and _didn't_  know he had taken up residence there (in other words, if I lacked any context regarding his current residence) and asked him about them naans, and he responded as in your comment, I would assume that he was jess a-visitin in these here parts.

Comment: @TRomano Another example, because I think this is important: I'm in Koblenz. A German feller says to me: Do you speak English? I respond: Having lived all my life in the United States, I should hope so! Will Karl imagine that I have emigrated to Germany? I don't think so. The _default_ understanding of _all my life,_ absent anything to belie it, is that this life is still going on in the place named in the expression.

Comment: @P.E. Dant. Late seeing this too.  Is it not possible for the German feller to be in doubt about whether you still live in the US?